# Set user role, if an specific role created an user

Tags: user-roles, init, wp-create-user

Im Trying to set an user role. if an specific user role (sales-agents) create an user.

the created user should have the role b2b instead of customer

here is my try:

```
add_action( 'init', 'b2b_set_user_role' );
    function b2b_set_user_role() { 
   if ( is_user_logged_in() && wcb2bsa_has_role( get_current_user_id(), 'sales_agent' ) ) 
   { 
        $user->remove_role( ‘customer’ );
        $user->add_role( ‘b2b’ );
   }
}
```

i hope someone can help me

Comment: This ist not Working. Because the the sales agents is an plugin.
It has it own site to register users. Should be something with that: if ( is_user_logged_in() && wcb2bsa_has_role( get_current_user_id(), 'sales_agent' ) )

Comment: I tried everything but im not getting it.
maybe someone has that little knowhow to solve this:D

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/229779)

Comment: @d3mi I converted your _solution_ into a comment, posting comments as solutions gets you flagged as a spammer and possibly auto-banned

Comment: Also, where did you get `$user` from? You can't just pull variables out of thin air

Comment: @d3mi It is possible that the proposed code does not work due to the wrong role name. I used `sales-agents` as the name, but there is also `sales_agent` in the question. Check both forms. Replaced the `user_can()` function but it shouldn't matter to the end result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `user_register` [action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/), which is invoked after registering a new user.
To add or remove roles/caps, the `WP_User` class provides methods:

- [`add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_cap/), `add_role()`
- [`remove_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/remove_cap/), `remove_role()`

Your code might look like this:

```php
add_action( 'user_register', 'se385135_user_register' );

function se385135_user_register( $user_id )
{
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( !isset( $user->ID ) || $user->ID == 0 )
        return;
    if ( !in_array( 'sales_agent', $user->roles ) )
        return;

    $created_user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
    if ( $created_user === false )
        return;

    $created_user->add_role( 'b2b' );
    $created_user->remove_role( 'customer' );
}
```

Comment: This does not check if the person creating the user is a sales agent

Comment: This ist not Working. Because the the sales agents is an plugin. It has it own site to register users.

Should be something with that:

if ( is_user_logged_in() && 
     wcb2bsa_has_role( get_current_user_id(), 'sales_agent' ) )